# Django: how to loop through boolean fields and set all to false

Tags: python, django, boolean

So, I have a table called "order" that has a foreign key with the table "store". The order table has a boolean field set by default to false. When a new order is created, I need to loop through the boolean values associated with each individual store and set the other orders to false and the new order to true. Not sure how to create the for loop for that. First I tried to set it into the view, but maybe it can be put into the forms.py file? This my create code so far.

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()     


         return HttpResponseRedirect('/liquors/all')
     else:
          form = OrderForm()

          args = {}
          args.update(csrf(request))

          args['form'] = form    

          return render_to_response('create_order.html', args)
```

Models provided upon request, you shouldn't need anything except the order model:

```
    class Order(models.Model):

       OrderID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       storeID = models.ForeignKey(Store)    
       DateCreated = models.DateField('Date Created', auto_now_add=True)
       OrderName = models.CharField('Order Name', max_length=25 )
       Active = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: can you show the models.

Comment: it is hard to write good answer if you don't provide the models!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must `return render_to_response('create_order.html', args)` one indentation back. so that validation form will not affected. you don't need to use `csrf request` if you are using `render`. `I think there is no need to use OrderId in Order model, since it is automattically created. ie id`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from <appname>.models import Order,Store

def create(request):
    if request.POST:            
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #i just assume the storeid variable is exist in request.POST and it is ID.
            store_data=Store.objects.get(id=request.POST['storeid'])
            #here you might need to update the other orderform to false
            Order.objects.filter(storeID=store_data).update(Active=False)                
            fo=Order(storeID=store_data,Active=True)
            frm_order=OrderForm(request.POST,instance=fo)                
            frm_order.save()                  
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/liquors/all')
    else:
        form = OrderForm()                  
    return render(request,'create_order.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: I know about the indent, that's just how it was copy and pasted into here. And to realign everything but I guess I missed that one. In any rate, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Yep. slipped my mind to just filter for the active order. the storeid is not passed in through the form like you have it, but that was easy to adjust, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the order object's meta object to loop through the fields. Ex.

```
for field in order._meta.fields():
    if type(field) = django.db.models.fields.BooleanField:
       setattr(order, field.name, True)
```